# How can I tell when a function was called for the first time in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a memory game, and  need to start a timer after clicking the first card. 
How do you do that?

Thanks

Comment: Use a flag. For a better answer please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: with a variable that stores the first click you can. but we don't write code for you. please have a look on how to ask here.

Answer (score 2):

Set a timestamp when the function is called, then when you want to see how much time is passed, compare the current time to the timestamp. Something like this will give you elapsed time in milliseconds:

```
var startTime;

function MyFunc(){
   startTime = Date.now();
   //My code...
}
function GetTimeElapsed(){
   var elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
   return elapsedTime;
}
```

Comment: @RakefetZeiman If this answered your question, please consider marking it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function yourFunction() {
    // Check to see if the variable firstTime has been initialized
    if ( typeof yourFunction.firstTime == 'undefined' ) {
        // first time code goes here
        yourFunction.firstTime = false; //do the initialisation 
    }
    else{
        // non first time code goes here ;)
    }
}
```